# LVM 2 snapshots and free blocks

Tags: linux, snapshot, lvm

LVM 2 snapshots works as COW. However the block may change even if it is not used anymore. As SSD disks may need marking of free/used blocks to better manage blocks, the API was introduced into Linux to mark free/used blocks.

My question is - does LVM use this API? I.e. are blocks are copied on every change or only if filesystem cares about contents?

Comment: Do you have any pointers to information about this new API?

Comment: Pretty sure he's referring to discard/TRIM support: http://lwn.net/Articles/293658/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blocks are copied on every change.